# Execute cron job by PHP

Tags: php, linux, cron, cpanel

I am using cPanel for my site, I want to set up a new cron job on triggering an event by PHP.
Also I want to delete previously exiting cron job while creating new cron.

Also I want to set start and end date/time for the new cron

**Is that possible? Please help on this.. I need it immediately**

Also where cPanel actually stores cron jobs, I had searched in my files in `home/etc/` I couldn't find.

Comment: crontab -e in shell, there is plenty of info, how to edit crontab

Comment: Yeah. but I also want to set start and end date/time for the new cron

Answer (score 1):

[Here](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/managing-cron-jobs-with-php-2/) is a tutorial on how to handle cron jobs in PHP.
Also, they'll be stored in /var/spool/cron/username